# Maintaining Structure of Form as Window Resizes, HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following form where there are two textboxes in inline format. When I try to compress the window horizontally they are no longer in the same horizontal span but rather one of the textboxes gets put one "line" lower while its preceding label stays on the same line as before. How can I change this so that the size compresses to stay on the same horizontal distribution as the window is resized horizontally.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>

  <!-- CSS Stuff -->

  <style>



    input[type=text]{
    width: 32%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    u {
    text-decoration: underline;
   }

  </style>




   <body>
   <p> <strong> <u> International Assistance - Reporting Template </u> </strong> <br><br> </p>
   <form> 
   <div id = "Page 1">
   <label id = "IdentificationLabel"> <u> Identification Page </u> </label>
   <br> 
   <br>
   <span> <label id = "DepartmentLabel"> Department :  </label>
          <input type = "text" id = "Department_TextBox" ></input> 
          <label id = "CRSID_Label" > CRS Identification Number :   </label>
          <input type = "text" id = "CRSID"> </input>
   </span>
   </form> 
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: What does 'mainting' mean? If you mean maintaining, make the window responsive. I'd also be great if you could include a live example

Comment: Go through this link http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Comment: What is the minimum screen width you are using?  Ultimately you are going to need to code a responsive layout for your form.  That means using CSS media queries to code different layouts for small, medium, large and extra large screen widths.  As someone else has said, you could look at the Bootstrap framework to help you with this, as it covers forms.